# related to jQuery

Tags: jquery

Cant submit form in .dialog() of jQuery

Comment: I guess you hit the submit question button too fast ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you speak about dialog box of jQuery UI.

You can submit a form in this dialog box. See the help to create a modal form with jQuery UI  : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form